# Expected { before interface

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Why am I getting the above compilation error in all of my source files after creating editing this file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate;


@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
    id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
    UITextField *textField;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;


@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
@end


@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end

-(IBAction) textChanged:(id) sender;
```

After editing my flipsidecontroller.h to look like this. I get the error in all of my other source files. Like this one:

```
    //  MainViewController.h
//  MVC
//
//  Created by Nick Martin on 3/31/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Nick. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> {
    UILabel *label;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender;

@end
```

It is complaining about the interface declaration for each of my controllers???

Thanks in advance for the help!

Update - put the textChanged event into the interface

```
//  FlipsideViewController.h
//  MVC
//
//  Created by Nick Martin on 3/31/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Nick Martin. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate;


@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
    id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
    UITextField *textField;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;


@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
@end

-(IBAction) textChanged:(id) sender;  //DOH!!! 

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `textChanged:` method isn't in an interface or protocol. Did you mean to include it in `FlipsideViewController` or `FlipsideViewControllerDelegate`?

Comment: That was definatley a problem :) However.. now I get the same error on the @protocol declaration? I updated my post to show the new flipsideviewcontroller. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
-(IBAction) textChanged:(id) sender;
```

but it seems to have fallen outside of your @protocol after the @end.

Comment: Thanks I saw that. I have updated the post to show that the action is now within the protocol. However the error is on the @protocol declaration within the flipsideviewcontroller.h now

Comment: The method is still not within the protocol or the interface.

Comment: Yup, textChanged is not in a @protocol or @class here. Unless you've posted the wrong code, that's the problem.